# Changing the font for a string-array used in an ArrayAdapter

Tags: listview, fonts, android-arrayadapter

I have seen a number of proposed solutions for dealing with changing the font of an `ArrayAdapter` including suggestions to **extend the ArrayAdapter class and override the getView() method. In this method you have to inflate a new view or re-use convertView and set the typeface for this view.**

I can see how that works with a `TextView` just fine.

However, it seems like most of these solutions are still actually working only with a `TextView` within the `ArrayAdapter` and not a `ListView`. I have a `String-Array` that is displayed within a `ListView` and I would like to be able to change the font of the `ListView` (not a `TextView`).

If not, alternatively, is there a way to display a string-array within a `TextView`?
(sorry if this is a very basic question but I'm new to Android)